# Transforming GRIB file into GeoTIFF that is correctly georeferenced using Python GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing, grib

I am trying to transform a GRIB file into a GeoTIFF to be used in a ArcGIS, but am having trouble getting the image to display in the correct location. I have been able to create a GeoTIFF, using GDAL in Python, that shows the data but is not showing up in the correct location when brought into ArcGIS. The resulting image is below.

[image: Location Issues]

The data I am working with can be downloaded from: https://gimms.gsfc.nasa.gov/SMOS/SMAP/L05/

I am trying to project the data into WGS84 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere), EPSG: 3857

Note: I have tried bringing in the data via ArcMap by creating a Raster Mosaic which should be able to work with GRIB data, but I didn't have any luck. I have also tried using the Project Raster tool, but ArcGIS does not like the default projection that comes from the GRIB file and gives an error.

The code I'm using:

```
import gdal

src_filename = r"C:\att\project\arcshare\public\disaster_response\nrt_products\smap\20150402_20150404_anom1.grib"
dst_filename = r"C:\att\project\arcshare\public\disaster_response\nrt_products\smap\smap_py_test1.tif"

#Open existing dataset
src_ds = gdal.Open(src_filename)

#Open output format driver, see gdal_translate --formats for list
format = "GTiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( format )

#Output to new format
dst_file = driver.CreateCopy( dst_filename, src_ds, 0 )

#Properly close the datasets to flush to disk
dst_ds = None
src_ds = None
```

I am not very well versed in using GDAL or GDAL in Python.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you are also looking for an ArcMap/ArcPy solution then please ask about that in a separate question so that this one can stay focused on GDAL/Python.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/54099090/820534